# Connecting Flask app to a Websocket server

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, websocket, flask-sockets

Not able to connect a Flask app as a websocket client to another websocket server.

I tried to look around how to implement this, but the only solution i found is when the connection is Short-lived one-off send-receive.

So, when I make a Long-lived connection, Flask app is not running anymore. I guess the problem, is because both of them are running "forever".

so if run the following code first, flask app won't run, and if I do the opposite the websocket connection won't be established.

```
 websocket.enableTrace(True)
 ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(config["WS_URI"],
                                on_message = on_message,
                                on_error = on_error,
                                on_close = on_close)
 ws.on_open = on_open

 ws.run_forever()
```

a sample Flask app:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "index"
```

Comment: Hi. I have exactly the same problem as you. Did u use the `WebSocket` class under "Websocket Example" [here](https://websocket-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html)? It makes it possible to incorporate Websocket-client into Flask Framework. Just close the connection when u close your app. Pls correct me if this is not feasible.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found was to run them on different processes. 
I wrote a small [post explaining the details](https://medium.com/@kendhia/run-python-webserver-flask-as-a-websocket-client-also-175c130f7ca4).

Comment: I don't understand how this is a solution. Shouldn't ASGI mean that you can run all of this at the same time in the same process?